# Unable to use fork repository in my Laravel project - "Could not find a matching version of package"

Tags: php, laravel, git, composer-php

I made my fork (https://github.com/digital-bird/LaravelShoppingcart) of someone's fork (https://github.com/hardevine/LaravelShoppingcart).

I want to use my fork in my Laravel project + **I want to modify it in the future**.

1) I removed the hardevine's fork from this project via `composer remove hardevine/shoppingcart`

2) Then I modified `composer.json` in my fork with:

- new name: `"name": "digital-bird/shoppingcart",`
- new author
- under require I added: `"hardevine/shoppingcart": "dev-master",`
- finally I added repositories section:

⬇️

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/digital-bird/LaravelShoppingcart"
    }
],
```

so new `package.json` of my fork looks like: https://github.com/digital-bird/LaravelShoppingcart/blob/master/composer.json

3) I pushed this to my fork's master branch

4) I went to my Laravel project and I typed:

```
composer require digital-bird/shoppingcart
```

I'm getting the big red error:

> **[InvalidArgumentException]**   Could not find a matching version of
>   package digital-bird/shoppingcart. Check the package spelling, your
>   version constraint and that the package is ava   ilable in a stability
>   which matches your minimum-stability (stable).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add  this:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/digital-bird/LaravelShoppingcart"
    }
],
```

to `composer.json` of your main Laravel project instead of your library. Also adding `"hardevine/shoppingcart": "dev-master",` seems to be pointless and it probably will create some conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will try and let you know, stay tuned.

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks a lot for your hints, all went very smoothly and I learnt something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit your Github repository to [Packagist](https://packagist.org/about)

Comment: There is no need to register fork in packagist  if you add it to `repositories` section of project which are using this fork.

Comment: Composer makes a call to packagist.org

Comment: So if you type in composer require <author-name>/<package-name> it searches packagist.org.

Comment: Composer will prefer package from repositories and use version from Packagist only if there is not such package defined in one of specified repositories. There is no need to clutter the Packagist by forks used in one project only.

Comment: Just to chime in, Rob is right. You can check the composer docs section on repositories. This will directly check the `composer.json` inside a git-repo to check if a package is available. No need to use packagist. See: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository